# IE-only text field background image

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I'm attempting to fix my CSS to allow older IE's to view my web site as best as possible.

I'm using 'border-radius' to style form fields giving them rounded corners. For the older IE's I'm using the background image below--

http://studio.allanbendy.com/sites/all/themes/studio_allanbendy_7/i/form-textfield-bg.gif

```
.form-textfield {
background: url("/i/form-textfield-bg.gif") no-repeat bottom right;
background-attachment: fixed;
height: 15px;
width: 362px;
}
```

Unfortunately the CSS above does not seem to style the text field on IE 7 and 8. It works just fine on IE 6.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `background-attachment: fixed;`. Because IE6 ignores this for non scrollable elements it's displayed there. But at all the attachment definition makes no sense, if you want to style a single element.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an IE-specific graphic, I'd recommend using [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/) to do rounded corners in IE.

It's a great solution to get IE to support standard CSS `border-radius` style.

Comment: Thanks, I had considered it, but for a few form elements, loading another js file is unnecessary.